# The keyboard doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, asus

I installed Ubuntu Desktop LTS 22.04 on an [ASUS TUF Gaming A15 laptop (2023)](https://www.asus.com/laptops/for-gaming/tuf-gaming/asus-tuf-gaming-a15-2023/techspec/). After the launch, my keyboard did not work. This is a new laptop model, which probably caused the problem. I will be glad if you help me :)

Comment: Did your keyboard work properly while running the Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LiveUSB installer?

Comment: @user535733 No, it didn't work at the installation stage

Comment: Then the hardware may be unsupported on that older kernel. Try a 23.04 LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment. Test *everything* in that environment - network, streaming, audio, etc. If it also doesn't work, then test a 23.10 pre-release LiveUSB. Be prepared for the possibility that you might need to restore Windows for a few months until compatibility for your hardware makes it into the Linux kernel.

Comment: @user535733 tell me, do I understand correctly that Ubuntu is the operating system that is one of the first to add a new Linux kernel to its builds? I like Linux Mint, but because of the smaller audience coverage, I suspect they have a smaller circle of developers.

Comment: The kernel on your installer image is what matters. You said that you installed "22.04", which has kernel 5.15, about 1.5 years old. 23.04 has kernel 6.2, a whole year newer. 23.10 (pre-release) will soon increment to kernel 6.3 (currently in -proposed)

Comment: Which kernel version is running? There is a problem with ASUS Ryzen  Laptops with some kernel versions. Some say it is fixed in 6.2.

Comment: @user535733 Perhaps manually installing the kernel can solve the problem?

Comment: I checked on Ubuntu 23.10, as well as on Fedora Workstation 38 with kernel version 6.2. The keyboard does not work on both of them. It is a pity that owners of new laptops are restricted in using open source software

Comment: Most vendors have no motivation to make it compatible or support something else than Windows. We all can be lucky that it is even **possible** to install something else than Windows. See UEFI.

Comment: As soon as there is a solution from kernel.org, it will be possible to fix this. Best ask them, how **you** can support them to fix it: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=217336

Comment: @Marco On Linux Mint 21.1, the keyboard and other computer components work perfectly fine **before installing updates**. However, after the system updates, various other issues arise.

Comment: Why not going back to Linux Mint 21.1 ? (no answer expected)

Comment: But if Linux Mint 21.1 worked. Which kernel was running while it worked?

Comment: @Marco The system had kernel version 5.15.0-56 installed, and after the update, the video driver stops working.

Comment: Have you tried linux 5.15 under Ubuntu?

Comment: @Marco I tried Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, now I will try 20.04.

Comment: To change the kernel there is no need to reinstall Ubuntu. Just install the kernel and reboot. Kernels can be found here (usually 4 deb files): https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: @Marco Thank you, perhaps it's worth notifying the guys from that forum that the issue is not present in older kernel versions, I think it will help in resolving it.

Comment: September, 2023 and I can confirm the kernel `6.2.0-33-generic` (used by Ubuntu 22.04) doesn't support the ASUS Keyboard. I hate vendors doesn't collaborate with open source solutions, I bought this laptop because I needed the GPU for AI develops. Let's wait october and see if Canonical integrates new kernel for this distribution (https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=217336)